# Mail deliverability rDNS best practice

Tags: exim, reverse-dns, email

I have an email server which sends email for multiple websites (different domain names each)

the reply-to will correspond to no-reply@website-a.com (or whatever their username/website is) but the return-path will always correspond to a single address that is common for all websites ie: bounce@web-host.com.

I understand that rDNS needs to work in order for my email to achieve maximum deliverability, but does rDNS need to correspond to the reply-to or the return-path or both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rDNS does not need to relate to the the reply-to or return-path.  Both these addresses should be valid addresses.

Correct rDNS for mail.example.com with address 192.0.2.5 would have:

- a PTR record for 192.0.2.5 pointing to mail.example.com,
- an A record for mail.example.com having an address of 192.0.2.5, and
- optionally a SPF TXT record for mail.example.com containing "v=spf1 a -all".

Your mail server should be configured to identify itself in the HELO command as mail.example.com, not example.com or mail.

If the domains you send mail for have an SPF record, they should allow your host to send email for the domain.  I do recommend that they have an [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) record.  I recently did a posting on [Securing your Email Reputation with SPF](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/securing-your-email-reputation-with-spf/).

Comment: so the rDNS needs to correspond to the domain given in HELO?
The A records for the domains given in HELO do not necesarily correlate to the ip of the interface used to send the mail (because the websites themselves only have one ip each, however the email server may have more than one ip per website it is serving) is this something that will flag me as spam?

If so, I can do something like send email-a.website-a.com in HELO so that the rDNS and A records match, but if that is not necesary I'd rather not send a subdomain in the HELO.

I do use SPF, thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, rDNS is used to verify whether your server really is `gmail.com` when you say it is.  (`gmail.com` is one of several frequently forged addresses used in HELO commands.  The actual server names gmail uses are different.)  Do use a subdomain for your mail server's address.  Having a records for example.com, and mail.example.com returning the same address is valid and common.  The PTR record should point to your subdomain.  Using a domain as the mail server's HELO name is a marker that you are sending Spam.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You should be able to configure your mail server to bind to only one Internet address.  This makes configuration simpler as you only need to configure the DNS PTR for one address.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, so I will need to send subdomains in the HELO.  My only gripe with that is that I will need to add a TXT record for the spf for each subdomain, which is ok (laziness was my reason for wanting to avoid subdomains.)  One more question (again, this is the result of laziness) would I be flagged if let's say one of the subdomains had 3 or 4 different A records, the ip itself would of course only have one rDNS.  So to speak, each subdomain would have the same set of As and each ip would have 1 PTR

Comment: Try to consolidate all your outgoing email to one server.  You should need only one email sub-domain for the email server to use in the HELO command.  My web servers have a standard SPF record ("v=spf1 -all") as they don't send email.  If you use the web server's address to send mail you could use "v=spf1 a:mail.example.com -all".  The reply-to and envelope-from addresses are typically domains (although for automated email like a web-site they may be from a reserved sub-domain.)

Comment: Requirements for the project dictate that clever email recipients should not be able to deduce that the email server is shared between multiple websites.  There is only one email server, however it has many public ips and each of those ips will PTR to a subdomain of the website it serves.  I was mistaken in thinking I would need more than one SPF record if an email HELO was from a subdomain, as that is not what determines the domain the SPF record to look up.  Anyway, I think I understand now, each A and PTR must have a 1:1 relationship, otherwise I'll be marked spam.  thank you!

Comment: Some sites, mine included, will verify SPF for the PTR record and/or HELO name (which should be the same).  This is more effective in identifying spam, than than checking the envelope or header addresses.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  To be safe I guess I'll add spf records for each subdomain too, which will be incredibly tedious...

Comment: If the subdomains are used only for the email server, you can use the same TXT record for each (v=spf1 a -all).  It will be a bit tedious, but you won't have to construct a record for each.  If you mail server will be the MX for the sending domains you can use (v=spf1 mx ~all) for each.  If the mail server IP address is the same as the corresponding web server's IP address you can use (v=spf1 a ~all) instead.

Comment: What problems should I expect if I configure my mailserver/rDNS/spf to use `example.com` rather than `mail.example.com`? You have me a bit worried with "Your mail server should be configured to identify itself in the HELO command as mail.example.com, not example.com…"!

Comment: @JackDouglas I have seriously considered penalizing or blocking servers using second level addresses as a lot of spam uses them, but few legitimate senders do.  I haven't seen any legitimate non-automated mail using servers with 2nd level domain addresses. I wouldn't be surprised if some services do filter such addresses to the spam folder.  Using example.com as your mailing domain is fine, just assign an MX to a sub-domain.